# Remove '|' special character from a string

Tags: jquery, special-characters, removeall

My question may find simple, But I am not getting it right. How could I remove "|" from a string so far I have used the following but Its not working

```
<div class="inner"> | ABCD || </div>
var txt=divVar.html();
```

1) `txt=txt.remove("|");`

2)`txt=txt.replace (/|/g, '');`

Comment: try this var txt=txt.split("|");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape '|' character:

```
txt=txt.replace (/\|/g, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` and `join`:

```
var newTxt = txt.split('|').join('');
```

To remove white space, you can use [$.trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/):

```
var newTxt = $.trim(txt.split('|').join(''));
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2sRnR/)**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove just '|' and not '||' than you can use the below mentioned solution

```
<div class="inner"> | ABCD || </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var str = $(".inner").html();
        alert(str);
        var FormatedStr = str.trim().replace('|', '');
        alert(FormatedStr);
    });
</script>
```

Else, if you want to replace both than use below

```
<div class="inner"> | ABCD || </div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var str = $(".inner").html();
            alert(str);
            var FormatedStr = str.trim().replace('|', '').replace('||', '');
            alert(FormatedStr);
        });
    </script>
```

Hope this help you to solve your problem

Thanks
Prashant